# Call php function inside echo <<<html?

Tags: php, html

i have searched a lot and still no chance, is there a way for calling a php function inside echo HTML ?

i also tried this and not worked.

```
<?php

echo <<<HTML

[HTML PARTS..]

<td colspan="2">its function: <? $z = func($x); echo $z; ?> </td>

...

HTML;

?>
```

function works outside of html.

Comment: Have you considered using a template engine?

Comment: yes (if i get ur mean) DreamWeaver, and phpstorm for coding..

Comment: That's an editor, not a template engine...

Answer (score 3):

You need to do:

```
<?php
$z = func($x);
echo <<<HTML

[HTML PARTS..]

<td colspan="2">its function: {$z} </td>

...

HTML;

?>
```

Or you could just not use heredoc:

```
<?php
// your php code
?>

[HTML PARTS..]

<td colspan="2">its function: <? $z = func($x); echo $z; ?> </td>

...

<?php
// your php code
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You can insert variables as per usual, so you'll need to calculate this before hand.

Answer (score 0):

Echoed text isn't evaluated. To interpret "stringed" code you'd need [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), although it's a very deprecated command, since it's dangerous.

A better option would be to concatenate the result of those function calls to the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Results need to be calculated beforehand. Only variables get parsed